# Getting Sharepoint Users and comparing them with SPList field

Tags: 2007, list, development, splistitem, user

I have a Custom SPList that has a field "Assigned To", now I can add as many items as I want, and they can have same title and same User they are assigned to, but what I want is a script so that I only get the Distinct number of user's email address, e.g. if a user is assigned to more then 1 item, I will get there email address just once, here is the code I wrote down but i dont think if its good enough.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("www.local.com"))
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList mySourceList = web.Lists["ListName"];

            SPQuery mySourceListQuery = new SPQuery();

            mySourceListQuery.Query =

                "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' />" +
                         "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                "</OrderBy>";



            SPListItemCollection mySourceItemColl = mySourceList.GetItems(mySourceListQuery);


                foreach (SPUser user in web.Users)
            {
                foreach (SPListItem mySourceListItem in mySourceItemColl)
                {
                    name = mySourceListItem["AssignedTo"].ToString();

                    name = name.Substring(name.IndexOf("#") + 1);

                    if (user.Name == name)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(user.Email);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I dont think if it even works properly as it's not going through all of them, any suggestions please

CHeers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Used SPUserField property instead so I didn't required to compare users with list items anymore.